Overall row summary section divider in rtables
I'm trying to build an rtable with the following requirements:

Overall counts at the top
Counts of rows by a group and subgroup
Unindent groups/subgroups by one level
Use section dividers (blank lines) in between each group
Use a section divider after the overall counts line to visually separate it from the rest of the table

It's the last requirement that I'm having trouble figuring out the correct solution for.
As an example, with the following data:
iris2 <- iris
iris2$group <- rep(letters[1:3], 50)

I want to create a table that looks like this:
               all obs   
—————————————————————————
Overall      150 (100.0%)
                         
setosa        50 (33.3%) 
  a           17 (11.3%) 
  b           17 (11.3%) 
  c           16 (10.7%) 

versicolor    50 (33.3%) 
  a           17 (11.3%) 
  b           16 (10.7%) 
  c           17 (11.3%) 

virginica     50 (33.3%) 
  a           16 (10.7%) 
  b           17 (11.3%) 
  c           17 (11.3%)

The only way I have been able to achieve this is with the following but it seems like a clunky way to do it:
library(rtables)

cfn <- function(df, labelstr, .N_col) {
  n <- nrow(df)
  in_rows(
    .names = c("Overall", " "),
    .list = list(rcell(c(n, n / .N_col)), " "),
    .formats = c("xx (xx.x%)", "xx")
  )
}

basic_table() |>
  summarize_row_groups(cfun = cfn) |>
  split_rows_by("Species", section_div = "", indent_mod = -1) |>
  summarize_row_groups() |>
  split_rows_by("group") |>
  summarize_row_groups() |>
  build_table(iris2)

Aside from extra code that's difficult to reason about what it's doing, another reason this isn't great is if I do something like trim_rows(), the extra row I forced under "Overall" is removed while the other section divs aren't.
Is there a more elegant way to create a section div under the first "Overall" row? (And as an aside, a better way to provide the "Overall" label for that row outside of using a tabulation function?)

The main issue in your code is that you rely on summarize_row_groups instead of analyze to produce the analysis rows. The first function should be used only after a split function (split_rows_by) to add a calculation (cfun) to the row split, i.e. a label row. Splits are divisions of the data, depending on the content of the split (sub-groups lets say, see example).
The following commented code explain the various steps to get what you need:
library(rtables)

iris2 <- iris
iris2$group <- rep(letters[1:3], 50)

# Custom function for overall initial tab
afun_tot <- function(x, .N_col) {
  n <- length(x)
  in_rows(c(n, n / .N_col), .names = "Overall")
}
# Custom function for the counts of different groups - note that the list object is different rows
afun_group <- function(x, .N_col) {
  n_grps <- table(x)
  in_rows(.list = lapply(n_grps, function(ni) c(ni, ni / .N_col)))
}

my_layout <- basic_table() |> # Basic table layout
  analyze("Species", afun = afun_tot, format = "xx (xx.x%)", section_div = "") |> # Overall initial tab
  split_rows_by("Species", section_div = "") |> # Formal division of rows by groups
  summarize_row_groups() |> # Addition of calculations to that division/subgrouping
  analyze("group", afun = afun_group, format = "xx (xx.x%)") # Analysis of groups

# Using the layout to produce the table once data is added
my_table <- my_layout |> 
  build_table(iris2) |> 
  print()
#>                all obs   
#> —————————————————————————
#> Overall      150 (100.0%)
#> 
#> setosa        50 (33.3%) 
#>   a           17 (11.3%) 
#>   b           17 (11.3%) 
#>   c           16 (10.7%) 
#> 
#> versicolor    50 (33.3%) 
#>   a           17 (11.3%) 
#>   b           16 (10.7%) 
#>   c           17 (11.3%) 
#> 
#> virginica     50 (33.3%) 
#>   a           16 (10.7%) 
#>   b           17 (11.3%) 
#>   c           17 (11.3%)

# See more details of the table structure
table_structure(my_table)
#> [TableTree] root
#>  [ElementaryTable] Species (1 x 1)
#>  [TableTree] Species
#>   [TableTree] setosa [cont: 1 x 1]
#>    [ElementaryTable] group (3 x 1)
#>   [TableTree] versicolor [cont: 1 x 1]
#>    [ElementaryTable] group (3 x 1)
#>   [TableTree] virginica [cont: 1 x 1]
#>    [ElementaryTable] group (3 x 1)

# If you use trim_rows, this removes the overall row in your test case but not here
# because it is an analysis row and not a label row (summarize_row_groups is only for label rows)
# trim_rows(my_table) # Nothing changes here

Created on 2024-07-23 with reprex v2.1.1
Note that more precise row removal can happen with prune_table(), but check pruning function there ;)
